# FancyBox не реагирует на обьекты, созданые через append()

Tags: jquery, javascript, append

`JS` код:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.main').on('click', '.block', function (){
         $('.main').append('<div class="block">Some Text<br/><a class="show" href="http://google.com">Add element</a></div>');
     });

     $("a.show").fancybox(
     {                       
         "padding" : 20,
         "imageScale" : false, 
         "zoomOpacity" : false,
         "zoomSpeedIn" : 1000
     }); 
 }); </script>
```

`html` код:

```
 <div class="main"><div class="block">Some Text<br/><a class="show" href="http://google.com">Add element</a></div> </div>
```

Когда новый виртуальный обьект  `".block"` добавляется к `".main"`, `Fancybox` не хочет с ним работать

[1]: http://fancybox.net , использую fancyBox 1.2.1

Comment: > Add element</a

Это у вас опечатка или действительно тэг не закрыт?

Comment: опечатка, исправил

Answer (score 1):

`fancybox` и не должен работать с новыми ссылками в этом случае. Вы добавляете `fancybox` для всех `a.show`, существующих на момент выполнения скрипта. На всех `a.show`, появившихся после (динамически добавленные), `fancybox` не добавлен. 
После того, как вы добавляете новую ссылку, необходимо для нее инициализировать `fancybox`.

Как вариант:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.main').on('click', '.block', function (){ 
    $('.main').append('<div class="block">Some Text<br/><a class="show" href="http://google.com">Add element</a></div>');
    $("a.show:last").fancybox({                       
      "padding" : 20,
      "imageScale" : false, 
      "zoomOpacity" : false,
      "zoomSpeedIn" : 1000
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: мне посоветовали
$(".main a.show").fancybox({ ... }); или .Live()
только ничего с этого так и не зароботало

Comment: .Live() в данном случае бесполезен - так как вы не отслеживаете события на ссылке.
$(".main a.show").fancybox({ ... }); должен работать корректно. Основная задача вызвать его ПОСЛЕ того, как добавится новый элемент <a> Единственное отличие - я в примере отфильтровывал ссылки и брал только последний элемент ( свежесозданный ) и на него вешах  fancybox, а не переписывал по всем ссылкам.

Comment: как вариант:

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.main').on('click', '.block', function (){
            $('.main').append(...);
            $("body").trigger("updateFancybox");
        });
    
        $("body").on("updateFancybox", function(){
            $("a.show").fancybox(
            {                       
                "padding" : 20,
                "imageScale" : false, 
                "zoomOpacity" : false,
                "zoomSpeedIn" : 1000
            }); 
        });
     });

Answer (score 0):

Советую подключить более свежую версию [Version 1.3.4](http://fancybox.net/home) или даже [fancyBox version 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)
и использовать метод [$.fancybox.showActivity()](http://fancybox.net/api) (смотрим в самом низу страницы), а пример использования, можно найти [в этих примерах](http://fancybox.net/blog) (смотрите код, после строки "*Simple validation; submit data using Ajax and display response*"). Там показано, как подключать fancybox к динамически добавляемому контенту средствами Ajax, но естественно, что данный способ подойдёт и к вашему случаю.